# android Whatsapp like profile interface

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, whatsapp, android-cardview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am looking for a way to create a profile interface like whatsapp:

[image]

I used collapsing toolbar and a recyclerView with inside CardView but my interface had a lot of problems.

When I scoll the recyclerView the items inside start scrolling when the toolbar is collapsed and the space of scrolling turn in the same space where before (when the toolbar was open) there was the image.

When the toolbar is collapsed there is the shadow.

**This is the code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1f1f1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <org.test.myapp.objects.SquareImageView_OBJ
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffff336c"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_color"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**This is what happen:**

[image]

Comment: can you tell me what is org.test.myapp.objects.SquareImageView_OBJ ? I'm trying to develop the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recycler view must be moved outside to AppBarLayout. and Try this way

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/main_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#f1f1f1"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f1f1f1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <org.test.myapp.objects.SquareImageView_OBJ
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffff336c"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_color"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: @Albin Mathew can you tell me what is org.test.myapp.objects.SquareImageView_OBJ ? I'm trying to develop the same.

Comment: @GreenRobo its just  a square image view referenced by the –  user4789408 in his question.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `RecyclerView` out of the `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use NestedScrollView with CoordinatorLayout like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_header_height"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mainView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_header_height"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/appbar_profile_pic_height_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_profile_pic_height_width"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_header_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
                android:contentDescription="@string/userPictureDes"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user_circle_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/example_user_name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivAvatar"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_text_padding_top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/profile_name_text_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    >
    <!-- your view code here -->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: when using it I get problem described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183738)